# AWS S3 Deployment with CloudFront Error (This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it)

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to deploy my app with AWS S3 and CloudFront. I have set all my S3 permissions to public. However I keep get this error when I load up the browser: [ErrorPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwT4H.png)

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
  <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  <Message>Access Denied</Message>
  <RequestId>6904C81A14C40727</RequestId>
  <HostId>q2gu5sW67rAC6vVoBuOcdF7R5ifSKyRO+4APYpIOt/A+qSESs2vnkp/xYFi2VGzoX6v8Z3EAn8k=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am deploying this with Github actions. Where is the error possibly coming from? Is it from my config files or my CloudFront or S3 settings?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the Cloudfront error on "Default Root Object" setting.
There is a "Default Root Object" setting in the "General" settings of cloudfront.If this is not set, then this error occurs.

Even if you have set an "index document" for S3 on the backend, you need to set it again for cloudfront. Goto your cloudfront distribution and add 'index.html' in general setting of "Default Root Object" box.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is from S3 because of permission issues. From the screen shot, you don't have favivon.ico in the bucket and / will basically list the bucket, you may want to define the default root document in the CloudFront.

[Default root document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/DefaultRootObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

try changing the  ... by

```
window.open("...Link", "_self/_blank")
```

it worked for me in aws s3bucket. also changed the

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
} from 'react-router-dom';
```